Where/how to get the right baseboard replacement?
I have to replace a small section of my baseboard. The whole house is the same so I am really hoping to get the same as a replacement. Even the one room is big so I really do not want to replace the entire perimeter just for a few feet. This is how it looks like:

I went to Home Depot but clearly I couldn't find the same.
Is there any sort of standard (or quasi standard) for baseboards? How can I determine which kind I have and subsequently where to get it from?

No standards, but The Moulding Company in Santa Clara will have something similar. Take your sample.

Nice, I’ll try it there! Is Santa Clara coincidence or is it obvious that this question is from the Bay Area? :)

Not a coincidence. You mentioned San Mateo a while back. Also, google TMC, I forgot that they have multiple locations. I also have a custom molding supplier in the rolodex, if it comes to that, but they’re spendy!

Big box stores keep what sells.  If a low seller/old stuff, often they do not stock it.  You need to look for an old person or go to lumber/hardware store.

If all else fails in finding a close enough match, you can get custom mouldings milled.  Find a local place that offers such a service.  Take a sample of what you want to reproduce.  They will make custom knives that match the profile of the moulding you have.
But be prepared to pay for it.  There will be a large up-front cost to make the knives, then a machine set-up charge, then a $-per-foot charge to run the moulding you need, plus the cost of the raw lumber.
So unless you REALLY want to match that exact baseboard profile, sometimes it's cheaper to replace the whole room.  But if you do that, save the old pieces that you removed to potentially be re-used in another room that might need some baseboards pieces for other changes or repairs.

That looks like a fairly common, albeit old piece.
Mill work can have a number code to identify the shape.  Look on the back for a number, ( 3 digit normally) .
If you cannot find a number, take the sample to a lumber yard. Those places have a much greater selection of millwork than the bigbox stores.

That is a common piece of molding; the issue is that its dated. You'll be able to find something similar at a big box store. If your set on an exact match, take the sample to to your local millwork company and they can custom make the piece or, in most cases, tell you where you can purchase it. If the shop is busy, they are more likely to provide you that information, vs. if they are slow and need the business at the time.
